# How to add password verify system with the hashed password?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter version 3 by the way,
So I currently developing a new website for sales data record for any market. And I currently struggling in the registration system.
And what I meant is how to verify the hashed password with the user inputted password.

Here's the script

```
public function cek_login()
    {
        $email          = set_value('email');
        $password       = set_value('password');
        

        $result         = $this->db->where('email', $email)
                                    ->where('password', $password)
                                    ->limit(1)
                                    ->get('account');
        if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            return $result->row();
        } else{
            return array();
        }
    }
```

`
and the models are

```php
public function loginproses()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            redirect('/');
        } else{
            $auth = $this->M_login->cek_login();
            
            if($auth == FALSE)
            {
                
                echo '<script>
                window.location.href="'.base_url('C_login').'";
                alert("Terjadi kesalahan silahkan cek ulang Email dan Password anda");
                </script>';
            } else{
                    
                if($auth['verified'] = 1){
                     echo '<script>
                                window.location.href="'.base_url('C_login').'";
                                alert("Email");
                                </script>';
                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_userdata('id', $auth->id);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('email', $auth->email);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('nama', $auth->nama);
                    echo '<script>
                    window.location.href="'.base_url('C_login').'";
                    alert("Login Berhasil");
                    </script>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert the input password to hash and then compare with the existing password

Comment: Could you reply with the script? it would be helpful for me

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php are built right into PHP, and about as easy as they could be. If you've tried implementing them but have a problem, please post a [mcve] and a clear problem description.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the links, and sorry for the mistake. I'll be better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I strongly believe that you need to do a lot of learning, I'll just leave this answer to point you to the right direction as you're working on your project.

For the registration, you need to **hash** the password using PHP's inbuilt hash function `password_hash()`. So your registration function should look like so:

```
public function cek_register()
{
    // get other fields for the registration and validate
    $user_password = $this->input->post('password'); // password field

    // Hash the password
    $hashed_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // You can store the $hashed_password in your database as you wish
}
```

The for login, you need to verify the password like so:

```
public function cek_login()
{
    // First you check if the supplied email is stored in the database
    // If yes, you get the password field of that stored email
    // Then you verify the password if it matches which the user has entered like so:
    if ( password_verify($the_entered_password, $the_password_stored_in_the_database) )
    {
        // The user is valid, log user in
    }
    else 
    {
        // Wrong password, show error message
    }
}
```

Here are some links you should check out:
[Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
[Password Verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)